# tib:base64-to-string giving error in tibco bw 6.3

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

In a mapper activity I have passed the encoded data to tib:base64-to-string but while running it, getting the initialization error as follows.

> ERROR [Job_Executor0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application -
>   TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-600026: Failed to start BW Application
>   [ServiceNow.v1.0.application:1.0]. Reason: TIBCO-BW-FRWK-600053:
>   Failed to initialize BW Component [ComponentAssyst_Attachment].
>    com.tibco.bw.core.runtime.api.BWEngineException:
>   TIBCO-BW-CORE-500232: Failed to initialize BW Component
>   [ServiceNow_Attachment], Application [ServiceNow.v1.0.application:1.0]
>   due to activity initialization error.    
>   com.tibco.bw.core.runtime.ActivityInitException: TIBCO-BW-CORE-500618:
>   Failed to initialize the activity [TransformXml] in process
>   [ServiceNow.v1.0.ServiceNow_Attachment], module [ServiceNow.v1.0] due
>   to unexpected activity lifecycle error.    
>   java.lang.AssertionError: resolver cannot be null.
>
> 23:22:36.900 INFO  [Job_Executor0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application -
>   TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300008: Stopped BW Application
>   [ServiceNow.v1.0.application:1.0]

can anyone help me on this to resolve this on priority.

Comment: Can you attach  your process?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's because you mapped the encoded data in tib:base64-to-string, it seems more like an error due the version, try to increment the version and all the modules must have the same version.